# Symfony2 - Doctrine2 FK naming strategy

Tags: php, symfony, oracle10g, doctrine-orm

Hi all I am currently working on big multienvironment extranet applications based on oracle databases. As our schema are not only used by the ap, we need to have precise naming conventions. 
After a bit of research, I'm still wondering if there is a way to implement Doctrine2 FK or any constraints naming strategy to avoid the oracle fk_xxxxxxxxx autogenerated names. Based on sf2 framework of course.

Answer (score 1):

There's a section in the Doctrine2 docs site that talks about [implementing a naming strategy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html), does that cover it?

**EDIT**

In terms of this linking to Symfony2, you'll need to register the service in a bundle, and reference that within the config.yml:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: em1
    entity_managers:
        em1:
            mappings:
                YamlBundle: ~
            naming_strategy: my_bundle.naming_strategy.default
```

Comment: yes thanks for the hint, I saw this information on the doc but I think the fk naming convention is not taken into account yet...

Answer (score 0):

I researched the exact same question.

The opinion of the maintainers is that **doctrine does not want to allow you to override the naming strategy for foreign key constraints**.

Source: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3753#issuecomment-244025830